# How to fix the sound in Skype after starting TeamSpeak 3?

Tags: 12.10, skype, teamspeak

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 64b.

I installed Skype for Linux (4.1 from Skype site for Ubuntu 12.04 multiarch) and then installed TeamSpeak 3 (downloaded, extracted and run ts3client_linux_amd64)

My problem is that when I start TeamSpeak I lose all sounds in Skype.

Then when I close TeamSpeak after a few moments Skype regains all sounds... any ideas?

Skype is set up to use pulse as mic, output and ringer.

Comment: I had a similar issue with VLC and Skype when I was using ALSA as the output device in VLC and PulseAudio as output device in Skype. Later I moved both to PulseAudio and the problem was resolved. Check the playback settings in TeamSpeak 3 to see if it is using something other than PulseAudio

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with SkyPE on ubuntu 12.10 on my ThinkCentre Edge 72z. It is an AIO which has mic, speaker, and camera build-in.

I may use the pre-installed recording program to record my sound. Playback is okay, too. But when I test with SkyPE, only the speaker works. It doesn't record my sound.

After I change the mic in options from default to "**Integrated Camera, USB Audio (h2:1,0)**",  it works correctly. I may heard my sound from mic.

Wish it help!